# Custom dependency for BackgroundService

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to pass user information to service layer like this (in net core web app):

```cs
services.AddScoped<RequestInfo>(provider =>
{
    var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    var userJson = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity).FindFirst("LoggedInUser").Value;
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJson);

    return new RequestInfo(int.Parse(user.UserId), user.ClientId);
});
```

This should work for controllers and services, but I also have BackgroundService to handle messages. I'd like to use user information from message before I resolve service to handle message. Is it possible to achieve or any workaround?  Something like (pseudo code)

```
using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

SetupUserInfo(..have no access to ServiceCollection .., contract user info);

var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(..my type);
```

**Update**
My best idea

```cs
services.AddScoped<RequestInfo>();

var info = provider.GetRequiredService<RequestInfo>();

info.UserId = .. get info from http context somewhere in middleware (for API)
info.UserId = .. get info from message before resolve of main dependency (for Background service)
```

Comment: Since that code is running on a background thread, it doesn't have access to information that comes from the web-request thread, especially because that request might already be gone. The solution, therefore, is to pass the required information on to the background thread as part of the message. This can be done, for instance, by wrapping each message in an envelope that contains the required metadata for the background operation to function.

Comment: Also, Don’t inject runtime data into application components during construction. The problems with this and possible solutions can be found [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data).

Comment: This sound like something that should be in middleware.

Comment: @Steven sure, httpcontext has no sense for background. Information come with a message, and my goal was to inject this information at runtime by either overriding factory method, either resolve dependency with overrides, but it looks like its not possible, at least with native DI framework (I did this trick years ago with asp.net web api + delegating handler + ninject di or something similar). Thanks for link, but I not agree when general concepts become an icon. If you know what you are doing you are safe.

Comment: Hi Anton, not sure how that would ever work if you're queing messages from a web request thread and execute them on a background thread, when you're not capturing the web request's user information with the message. I'm very interested to see what trick you applied years ago, because my gut feeling tells me this won't work independently of which DI Container you use.\

Comment: @Steven as I said previously, all necessary information to create new RequestInfo object come with message. All I want is to override factory method - new one instead of httpcontext access will use information from message. I found that some frameworks like autofac allowed (in a past) to update container. My problem - find common mechanism for both api context and background service to pass info for next usage in factory method. It can be intermediate object, which I will populate in middleware for api, and manually before resolving main object for background service

Comment: I tried with what you updated,httpcontext always return nul in backgroundservice,just as the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#httpcontext-isnt-thread-safe descirbes: HttpContext is not thread safe,IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext may be null if accessed outside of the request flow

Comment: @RuikaiFeng where did you saw in my update that I use httpcontext for background? For background you should directly set properties for RequestInfo (in my case I take data from message)